# Tuple specific extraction with for loop due to large quantity of lists

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to extract more than 1 pair of tuples in even or odd positions.  For example the first and the last.  I have read many questions and all of them are referring to how to extract a specific one from each tuple, but I have to have 2 pairs.
I am using for example test2 (already made as tuple) and currently trying to figure it out with:

```
Tuplewanted=[x[0::1] for x in Tuple]

Tuplewanted
Out[44]: 
[(778933.8147968281, 5803816.850292235),
 (778999.2820487045, 5804014.491034968),
 (779011.4321377204, 5804048.532974694),
 (779024.8198435705, 5804081.474176192),
 (779039.3061023126, 5804115.648560766),
 (779055.1628175485, 5804146.376816435),
 (779072.6698779828, 5804178.971719031),
 (779121.9406760866, 5804267.038294602)]
```

while I want only the 1st tuple and the last

```
Tuplewanted= [(778933.8147968281, 5803816.850292235),(779121.9406760866, 5804267.038294602)]
```

Anyone? 
Note that `Typewanted[0]` and `Typewanted[7]` and the `.append` cannot work since I have a list with more than 100000 of those tuple lists.

**Solution**

```
Tuplewanted['coords']=[ix.coords[::len(ix.coords)-1]for ix in Tuple.geometry]
```

Thank you again

Comment: `[Typewanted[0],Typewanted[-1]]` ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you want exactly. If you just want the last tuple, you can do this :`list[-1]`

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: But I have not the reputation to comment ;)

- except for comments to my own posts.

Comment: @hajef r Thank you.  My description is bad since I am new to python and got heavily involved with it for a thesis without knowing much.  I have 'code'   motorwaySimple=[[motorway.loc[ind].geometry.coords[i] for i in range(len(motorway.loc[ind].geometry.coords))][0::5] for ind in motorway.index]  or something like this to take the specific tuples that i need. My problem is that I have to have the first and the last tuple always and then maybe few tuples (since we are talking about coordinates).

Comment: If you have problems with iterations, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o